# Ubuntu server 14 - vmplayer 4.0.6

Tags: vmware

Vmplayer 4.0.6 is free for  personal and commercial use. I use it in Windows 7.

After install vmplayer 4.0.6 (Ubuntu server 14) I have something like this (Screenshot) and I can not run the program:

[image]

The installation process:

```
sudo apt-get install build-essential linux-headers-$(uname -r)
ksudo bash ~/Downloads/VMware-Player
```

Thank you in advance for your help

Comment: This is a very old version, current is 12.1.0, perhaps try this?

Comment: I checked 12 - work but is not for commercial use:) I have to pay for this version